# Output and filter data from a XML url

Tags: functions, filters, api, xml

I have a URL provided by my Real Estate service that lists, in a XML file, every apartment and house that I have to sell.

The XML url lists every detail of every apartment, things like images, year of building, floor, prices, rent, etc.

I need to create a Real Estate WordPress website where I can list, from this url, all those apartments and house and also show a filter where I can filter apartaments by price, by location, etc.

Any clue on how to do this on WordPress?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Periodically read the XML file, parse it, and insert/update/delete your custom Wordpress "realestate" posttype. I have done this before, for various realestate clients.
Step 1 (the easy way): Find out if there is already a plugin/code to read your specific XML. There are probably dozens of others using the same XML structure to fill a (wp)website.

Step 2: Write your own plugin, define your own posttype.

Step 3: Periodically read in the XML and update the data (posts / post_meta).

Step 4: Create the views to display/filter your custom posttype

Every step includes a whole topic in Wordpress development, a bit too much to explain here.